# find location of a cell with an exact match in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to loop through `range a`  on `sheet a` and, search for each value in `range b` on `sheet b` and then add to a column in `sheet b` if there's a match.

Here's what I've got:

```
Function add_column_binary(sheet_name_from As String, col_from As Integer, sheet_to As String, col_to As Integer)

'   set range  - the range to be looped through to find key for serachign the second range
Dim first_range As Range
Set first_range = set_range(sheet_name_from, col_from)

'   set ragen - the range in teh second sheet to be repeatedly searched
Dim second_range As Range
Set second_range = set_range(sheet_to, col_to)

'   find last column
Dim last_col As Integer
last_col = Worksheets(sheet_to).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column

'   label last column
Worksheets(sheet_to).Cells(1, last_col + 1).Value = "Invited = 1"

Dim rows1 As Long
rows1 = first_range.Cells(rows.Count, col_from).End(xlUp).Row + 1 

Dim n As Long
Dim constructed_id As String

Dim find_result As Range


For n = 2 To rows1
    constructed_id = "ObjectID(" & first_range.Cells(n, 1) & ")"  ' format object id
    '  ****  I keep getting "run-time error '1004':"  ****
    '  ****  "Application-defined or object-defined error" ****
    With Worksheets(sheet_to).Range(second_range)
        Set find_result = .Find(constructed_id, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
     End With
Next n
Stop

End Function

Sub test_stuff()

    Dim x As Range
    Set x = add_column_binary("invitesOutput.csv", 3, "usersFullOutput.csv", 1)
End Sub
```

Is there a problem using `With` inside a `For` loop?

Comment: Are you having a problem using `With` inside a `For` loop?

Comment: @FreeMan I honestly don't know what the problem is.

Comment: what does `Set second_range = set_range(sheet_to, col_to)` return? It should be something like `"A1:A50"` or something like that.

Comment: Does it throw an error? Does it run to completion without error, but also without expected results? To the best of my knowledge, the answer to the question you've asked is `No`, but that's probably not what you're really after -- My bad, I see the error in the comment in your code.

Comment: @BranislavKollár yes, `second_range` is a range of cells.

Comment: Try losing the `With Worksheets(sheet_to).Range(second_range)` and just use `Set find_result = second_range.Find(constructed_id, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)`. You already defined this range.

Comment: @FreeMan it does throw an error.  I wrote it in the code in the `For` loop.

Comment: Yeah, @BranislavKollár has it. You're trying to provide a range object to the `Range()` method - it's expecting a string of some sort.

Comment: @BranislavKollár it no longer throws the error, but what is `find_result`?  is it also a range?  When I try `debug.print find_result.Address` it throws another error:  `Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set`.

Comment: Yes, the `Find()` methor returns a Range, specificly the first cell that is found. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178845%28v=office.12%29.aspx . As for the error : Did it find what it was looking for? Quote from the link "This method returns Nothing if no match is found. The Find method doesn’t affect the selection or the active cell."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code below :

```
With Worksheets(sheet_to).Range(second_range)
    Set find_result = .Find(constructed_id, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
 End With
```

To this :

```
Set find_result = second_range.Find(constructed_id, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Reason :
The `second_range` is already defined as a range and you can use it for the `Find()` method.
The **Range** in `Worksheets(sheet_to).Range(second_range)` was expecting a **String, representing a range** not a **Range object**. Therefore an error.

### Edit - Handling situation when nothing is found

To overcome the situation when nothing is fount use IF statement :

```
If Not find_result Is Nothing then 'Not Is Nothing, in other words is something
    'Your code
End if
```

Comment: this works, but how do I handle if nothing is found?  getting another error.

Comment: @dwstein I added an Edit for this situation.